# How do I count the occurrences of rows in a column having type str with respect to their category?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I would like to count the number of category occurrences using the app column name. Since there's no numeric column, `newapp = newapp.groupby(['App']).mean()`wouldn't work.

```
newapp = apps.drop([ 'Genres','Reviews','Content Rating','Size','Size','Type','Price'], axis=1)
newapp = newapp[newapp.get('Installs')>=1000000]
newapp1 = newapp[newapp.get('Rating')>=4]
newapp = newapp1.drop(['Rating','Installs'], axis=1)
newapp
```

[image]

The complete dataframe:

[image]

The Expected Output as being the category with the most good apps, where good app is installing at least 1 million and rating of at least 4:

GAME

Comment: please tell me if my solution works, in another hand could you copy and paste an example of your dataframe and your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
newapp[newapp['Installs'].ge(1000000) & newapp['Rating'].ge(4)].groupby('Category')['App'].size().idxmax()
```